# How can I return the ID based from its first name and last name in autocomplete in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, web

Here is the index.php code (I've got this online, credits to the owner):

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> Ajax php Auto Suggest </TITLE>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="js/script.js"></SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <center>

   <div class="main">
      <div class=""><a href="http://www.scriptime.blogspot.in">scriptime</a></span></div>
         <div id="holder"> 
         Enter Keyword : <input type="text" id="keyword" tabindex="0"><img src="images/loading.gif" id="loading">
         </div>
         <div id="ajax_response"></div>

   </div>
 </center>

 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here is the .php code (the config is working just fine).

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$keyword = $_POST['data'];
$sql = "select idPerson, firstName, middleName, lastName from ".$db_table." where ".$db_column." like '".$keyword."%'";
//$sql = "select name from ".$db_table."";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    echo '<ul class="list">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $str = ($row['idPerson']);
        $str1 = ($row['firstName']);
        $str2 = ($row['middleName']);
        $str3 = ($row['lastName']);
        //$start = strpos($str,$keyword); 
        //$end   = similar_text($str,$keyword); 
        //$last = substr($str,$end,strlen($str));
        //$first = substr($str,$start,$end);

        $final = '-'.$str.' '.$str2;

        echo '<li><a href=\'javascript:void(0);\'>'.$str.' - '.$str1.' '.$str2.' '.$str3.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
else
    echo 0;?>
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT:
[If I click the value, I want that the textbox would return its ID only. How can I do that? I really need help. I still suck at this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txvQk.png)

Comment: Based on the picture I uploaded, this is the code: 

echo '<li><a href=\'javascript:void(0);\'>'.$str1.' '.$str3.'</a></li>';

Comment: how about just adding $row['id'] ? if the fieldname is 'id' of course.

Comment: "I got this online, credits to the owner". And the case for the defence, "well your honour I did credit the owner ..... didn't I?" :-)

Comment: I already did:  $str = ($row['idPerson']);

It still doesn't show only the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a bad practice to show the ID in the text field itself. What if the user wants to type in again? Of course you can do anything with jQuery, but I would suggest you to display the `id` **in front** of the field after it's selected.

Try the code below, where we have our `first name last name` in a `div`, with a unique `id` retrieved from the database, and whenever this div is clicked, we append the id and display it to the user.

Your PHP code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$keyword = $_POST['data'];
$sql = "select idPerson, firstName, middleName, lastName from ".$db_table." where ".$db_column." like '".$keyword."%'";
//$sql = "select name from ".$db_table."";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    echo '<ul class="list">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $str = ($row['idPerson']); 
        $str1 = ($row['firstName']);
        $str2 = ($row['middleName']);
        $str3 = ($row['lastName']);
        //$start = strpos($str,$keyword); 
        //$end   = similar_text($str,$keyword); 
        //$last = substr($str,$end,strlen($str));
        //$first = substr($str,$start,$end);

        $final = '-'.$str.' '.$str2;


        echo "<li><a href='javascript:void(0);'><div class='nameHolder' id='".$str."'>".$str1." ".$str2."</div></a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
else
    echo 0;?>
```

Add this JavaScript (rather, jQuery) to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".nameHolder").click(function(){ //check if any of the names is clicked

    if ($(".showID")[0])
    {  
        $('.showID').remove(); //remove if an id was shown before
    }

    var selectedID = $(this).attr('id'); //get the 'id' of the selected name

    $(".list").append("<b class='showID'>ID: "+selectedID+"</b>"); //append it to our HTML

    });

});

</script>
```

Although, this merely depends on the way you are doing the autocomplete function, and it could be manipulated easily using jQuery. But well, this is an approach to achieve what you're thinking of!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But I was looking for something like... when I type in the input box the name "Walter White...", the autocomplete would show the name Walter White and when I select it, its ID number would be placed in the text box instead of its name.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff, ah I see what you mean now. Updated my answer. Please let me know.

Comment: hi. I tried the code you gave and it's still not working :-(

Comment: How so? Could you plz check the console and see if you get any errors? If so, please paste it here.

Comment: I'm using notepad++. it's not showing any errors. However, there's a script.js file here. Maybe you'd want to take a look?

Comment: notepad++? I was talking about chrome/firefox console. Is it live? Are you able to provide any link to it?